# Wait for providers constructor to be ready before using it

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, ionic-framework, storage

In my application I am using a provider for authentication and one for loading the applications config file. The `auth` provider uses data from the `config` provider, though. So I would like the `auth` provider to wait for the `config` providers constructor to be ready, before calling it's `getSelectedConfig()` method. Right now I implemented the following mechanism

```
// AuthProvider
@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {

  private url:string;
  private token:string;

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    public config: ConfigProvider
  ) { 
    this.loadParams();
  }

  private loadParams() {
    this.config.ready().subscribe(
      ready => {
        this.config.getSelectedConfig().subscribe(
          config => { 
            this.url = config.endpoint;
            this.token = config.token;
          }
        );
      }
    )
  } 
}

// ConfigProvider (in seperate file, of course)
@Injectable()
export class ConfigProvider {

  private selectedConfig:Config = null;
  private configStorageKey:string = "selected_config";
  public readyObservable:Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(
      public storage: Storage,
      public http: HttpClient
    ) {
    this.checkStorageForConfig();
  }

  public ready(){
    return this.readyObservable;
  }

  public checkStorageForConfig() {
    this.readyObservable = Observable.create(
      observer => {
        this.storage.get(this.configStorageKey).then(
          config => {
            if(config){
              this.selectedConfig = config;
            }
            observer.next();
          }
        )
      }
    )
  }
}
```

So I create an Observable that can be given to `auth` to know whether `config` provider can be used already.

This method works, but I don't think it is a good solution. Yet I can't come up with a better one. I generally don't know how to handle such a situation.

In my mind I would like to simply call something like `this.config.ready().then( ... )` without introducing other Observables. But maybe this is the right way, after all.

Comment: Have a look at APP_INITIALIZER to load your config service before the app is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it by using await async/await maybe, if the logic started to increase much further i'd recommend having a separate service to handle onReady issues. This is just a simple rework:

```
// AuthProvider
@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {

private url: string;
private token: string;

constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    public config: ConfigProvider
) {
    this.loadParams();
}

private loadParams() {
    this.config.readyObservable.subscribe(
        ready => {
            if (ready) {
                this.config.getSelectedConfig().subscribe(
                    config => {
                        this.url = config.endpoint;
                        this.token = config.token;
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    )
}

// ConfigProvider (in seperate file, of course)

@Injectable()
export class ConfigProvider {

private selectedConfig: Config = null;
private configStorageKey: string = "selected_config";
public readyObservable: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new 
ReplaySubject(1);

constructor(
    public storage: Storage,
    public http: HttpClient
) {
    waitForStuffInConstructor()
}

public ready() {
    return this.readyObservable;
}
public async waitForStuffInConstructor() {
    await this.checkStorageForConfig();
    this.readyObservable.next(true);
}
public checkStorageForConfig() {
    this.storage.get(this.configStorageKey).then(
        config => {
            if (config) {
                this.selectedConfig = config;
            }
            observer.next();
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: This looks helpful, But it seems my `readyObservable` does not have the method `.next()` ?

Comment: Also `waitForStuffInConstructor` is not called, but I guess it should be called in the constructor, right?

Comment: Sorry was in a rush while answering as i was at work, i've edited it a bit so your using a replay subject which only emits when a next() value is given. and yes you call waitForStuffInConstructor() in the constructor. hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that's reasonable. Thank you. I'm fairly new to development with ionic/angular. Is doing this actually good practice or are there better ways?

Comment: I think as a method of communication between services it's absolutely fine. its also great because you can monitor changes in your config with your Observable and make changes based on it.